# wifi hotspot through intel AC7260 not connecting via intel N1030

Tags: 16.04, wireless, intel, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have installed Lubuntu 16.04 latest version alongside Windows 7 on an old dell laptop. I have Intel wireless card N1030 single band. My Ethernet cable has stopped working and campus wifi is slow so i am trying to connect to the  wifi hotspot that my room-mate creates. My room-mate is using Ethernet to access internet on his Windows 10 laptop and then [creates a wifi hotspot](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-turn-your-windows-10-pc-wireless-hotspot) on his machine from terminal without any 3rd party software. He starts the hotspot as:

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

I cannot connect to this wifi network even though i type the correct password. My room-mate has Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260 on Windows 10. His Ethernet connection is powered by I217-LM.

I am having difficulty figuring out what is the problem. My laptop is old but can connect to campus wifi. And the wifi he creates is also easily accessible on my smartphone. But i cannot connect to his wifi either through lubuntu 16 or windows 7. So i guess it might be problem on my side that i do not have the correct linux drivers. Or should another method to create wifi hotspot be tried? I am mostly concerned with getting the wifi connected on lubuntu as that is what i use. My lubuntu kernel is 4.8. I found this [link](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) where all drivers to be installed are listed. And i seem to have drivers for both of the wireless cards in my `/lib/firmware`. So i am confused how to fix this issue.

Please let me know if i should post extra info.

Comment: So you can't connect to it from Windows 7?

Comment: I cannot connect to the hotspot from Lubuntu 16 as well as Windows 7 but i am mostly concerned with getting it connected through Lubuntu 16 as that is my main OS. I don't care much about figuring it with Windows 7 as my old 4GB Dell laptop cannot handle Windows 7 well anyways.

Comment: The hotspot is being created from Windows 10.